# Paging,search & sorting of near of 100000 records

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, meteor

I have 100000 records in my database with 10 column

which are `int`, `float`

**My question**

I want to perform paging, search & sorting operation on this data.

I think i have two option.

either using Ajax request for each call or retrieve all data at time,perform operations like search, sort

suggest any better solution.

NOTE: Im using `Meteor.js` and `numbtel:mysql` package

Comment: Why not use meteor's publish and subscribe, rather than handling the raw ajax yourself?

Comment: If I use publish, it will load all data in browser, since is it ok to load unnecessary data in browser at first time?

Comment: You can limit the data sent through a publish

Comment: How can I do this in meteor?please give any example or demo.

Comment: `Meteor.publish('somePublish',function(){ return Collection.find({},{limit: 10}); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you can try bootstrap framework(data tables). it can easily to integrate for large number of rows

[including the DataTables Bootstrap files (CSS and JS)](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Comment: I am using Meteor for development, is i full-fill my requirement without any timing issue

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to perform the task:

1. Use jQuery Data table if you are retrieving all the records at once.
   [image]

--
If you follows this technique it will increase the loading time. It is consider better for less no of records. more more records it takes time on first time.

If you have less time for development then "Datatable is best". It already has all the feature you are looking for.

2. Second way is "ajax", it is a bit time taking. you have to code separately for
3. search
4. pagination etc.

So it all depends on time of development and type of app you are going to develop.

Comment: jQuery Data table is the best for me, how will I implement it?

Comment: Sneha: http://www.datatables.net/download/index or http://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/

Comment: The above links might help you out in implementation